# How to make test case for Constructor

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to make unit test cases for below class but i am getting exception when i run mvn clean test and i am not understand what is problem can some one help me how can i resolve this problem

eroor

```
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   ApplicationErrorHandlerTest.setUp:41 InvalidUseOfMatchers 
Misplaced or misuse...
```

### Class

```
public class BadRequestException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BadRequestException() {
        super();
    }

    public BadRequestException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

### Test case

```
public class ApplicationErrorHandlerTest {

    @Test
    public void BadRequestExceptionTest() throws Exception  {
        BadRequestException badRequestException1 = new BadRequestException();
        BadRequestException badRequestException2 = new BadRequestException(ArgumentMatchers.anyString());
        assertNotNull(badRequestException1);
        assertNotNull(badRequestException2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misuse `ArgumentMatchers.anyString()`.

For your use case you don't need it, you can just pass any string and check that its value was passed to the message field correctly, for example:

```
   public class ApplicationErrorHandlerTest {

        @Test
        public void BadRequestExceptionTest() throws Exception  {
            BadRequestException badRequestException1 = new BadRequestException();
            Strign testMessage = "testMessage";
            BadRequestException badRequestException2 = new BadRequestExceptiontestMessage);
            assertNotNull(badRequestException1);
            assertNotNull(badRequestException2);
            assertEquals(testMessage, badRequestException2.getMessage());
        }
   }
```

Regarding `ArgumentMatcher` - it should be used when you are Mocking your instance with mockito. Please see more details in the [official documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html).

In your example you don't mock anything with Mockito, just checking values with Asserts.

Answer (score 0):

Using `@Parameters` annotation to create a set of input data to run our test.

[You can follow the working example here.](https://www.guru99.com/junit-parameterized-test.html)